# NuGet init.ps1 causing debug into in console

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2013, nuget-package

We have an in-house NuGet package that has a readme.txt file that we want to display when the package is installed. To accomplish this we created a very simple init.ps1 file for the package that looks like:

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

$path = [System.IO.Path]
$readmefile = $path::Combine($installPath, "content\Content\fonts\globalcons\readme.txt")
$DTE.ItemOperations.OpenFile($readmefile)
```

It does what it's supposed to and opens the readme.txt when the package is installed, but it also spews the following in the Package Manager Console.

```
AutoHides             : False
Caption               : readme.txt
Collection            : {Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.DTE.WindowBase, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.DTE.WindowBase, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.DTE.WindowBase, 
                        Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.DTE.WindowBase...}
CommandBars           : 
ContextAttributes     : System.__ComObject
DTE                   : EnvDTE.DTEClass
Document              : System.__ComObject
HWnd                  : 0
Height                : 1039
IsFloating            : False
Kind                  : Document
Left                  : 1951
Linkable              : False
LinkedWindowFrame     : Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.DTE.WindowBase
LinkedWindows         : 
Object                : System.__ComObject
ObjectKind            : {8E7B96A8-E33D-11D0-A6D5-00C04FB67F6A}
Project               : System.__ComObject
ProjectItem           : System.__ComObject
Selection             : System.__ComObject
Top                   : 106
Type                  : vsWindowTypeDocument
Visible               : True
Width                 : 1432
WindowState           : vsWindowStateMaximize
HasBeenDeleted        : False
Events                : Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.DTE.WindowEvents
VisibilityEvents      : Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.DTE.WindowVisibilityEvents
Rect                  : 1951,106,1432,1039
OutstandingEventCount : 0
```

I know it's the aforementioned script that's causing it because if I comment out the `$DTE.ItemOperations.OpenFile($readmefile)` line the output doesn't show up in the Package Manager Console. What I can't figure out is what I'm doing wrong that is causing the output to show up every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an init.ps1 file to get a readme.txt displayed.  NuGet natively supports this as long as there is a readme.txt in the root folder of the package.  Note NuGet only displays the readme.txt for the package being installed and not for any packages it depends on.

But if you want to stick with your current approach, cast the return value from this method to `[void]`:

```
[void]$DTE.ItemOperations.OpenFile($readmefile)
```

Comment: I understand that NuGet will natively display a readme.txt in the root folder. Unfortunately we don't want to put it there, we want to put it in the content subfolder.

I'll try the void cast and see what happens.

Comment: FWIW we put the readme in both places.  The root as readme.txt so it appears automatically *and* in content as <packagename>ReadMe.txt so it appears in the project.